# proposition about boundary points of subset of topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a topological space and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Then:

1. $A$ is closed if and only if $\partial A$ is a subset of $A$
2. $A$ is open if and only if $A\cap\partial A=\emptyset$
3. $\partial A=\emptyset$  if $A$ is both open and closed

Here $\partial A$ denotes the boundary of $A$.

Comment: Yes! or maybe.. or NO. What is the question?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Comment: What is the definition of boundary you are using?

Comment: set of points which can be approached both from A and the outside of A

Comment: define "approached". The *exact* definition please.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\partial A := \overline{A} \cap \overline{X \setminus A}$.

(i) $A$ closed $\Rightarrow \partial A \subseteq A$:  we have $A =   \overline{A}$ so

$$ \partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{X \setminus A} = A \cap \overline{X \setminus A} \subseteq A. $$

$A$ closed $\Leftarrow \partial A \subseteq A$: We will show that $\overline{A} \subseteq A$, so that $\overline{A} = A$, giving equality and hence closedness. Suppose for a contradiction that we can find an $a \in \overline{A} \setminus A$. As $a \notin A$, $a \in X\setminus A \subseteq \overline{X \setminus A}.$ On the other hand we know that $a \in \overline{A}$. So $a \in \partial A \subseteq A$, a contradiction.

(ii) Suppose $A \cap \partial A = \emptyset$. We want to show that $A$ is open. So we will show that $A \subseteq A^{\circ}$. If this isn't true, we can pick $x \in A \setminus A^{\circ}$. Note that $A^{\circ} = X \setminus \overline{X \setminus A}$. So we see that $x \in \overline{X \setminus A}$. But $ x \in \subseteq A \subseteq \overline{A}$. So $x \in \partial A$. Hence $x \in A \cap \partial A = \emptyset$, a contradiction.

Suppose $A$ is open. Then  $$A \cap \partial A = A \cap \overline{A} \cap \overline{X \setminus A} = A \cap \overline{A} \cap (X \setminus A^{\circ}) = A^{\circ} \cap (X \setminus A^{\circ}) = \emptyset.$$

(iii) If $A$ is both open and closed, then:

Because $A$ is open, then by part (ii) we have $A \cap \partial A = \emptyset$.

But as $A$ is closed, we know that $X \setminus A$ is open. So again by part (ii) $(X \setminus A) \cap \partial A = \emptyset$.

But then $$\partial A = ((X \setminus A) \cap \partial A ) \cup (A \cap \partial A) = \emptyset \cup \emptyset = \emptyset.$$